# DB2: Need help on CASE / WHEN

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query that pulls the driver name and terminal numbers 
here:

```
SELECT UNIQUE D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME,
CASE
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '0' THEN 'LITHONIA'  
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '1' THEN 'MONTGOMERY' 
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '2' THEN 'BOWLING GREEN'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '4' THEN 'OOLTEWAH'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '40' THEN 'LEXINGTON SOUTH'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '41' THEN 'DURHAM'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '42' THEN 'LEXINGTON'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '43' THEN 'OKC'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '46' THEN 'STEVENSON'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '47' THEN 'TUPELO'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '48' THEN 'HUMBOLDT'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '49' THEN 'MURFREESBORO'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '5' THEN 'JEFFERSON CTIY'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '50' THEN 'LEWISBURG'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '52' THEN 'SAVANNAH'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '54' THEN 'FRANKLIN'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '6' THEN 'JACKSONVILLE'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '75' THEN 'VIRGINIA'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '8' THEN 'ATHENS'
WHEN TERMINAL_NUMBER = '9' THEN 'LATTA'
WHEN OTHER_CODE = 'COL' THEN 'COLOMBUS' 
END AS TERM 
FROM DRIVER D
WHERE D.ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
ORDER BY DRIVER_ID, term
```

However, I need it to have `colombus` be its own '`term`' column, the only problem is the drivers who may have other `code = 'col'` are also in terminal 0.

How should I rewrite this query to demonstrate that ?

[image: return results]

[image: drivers whose other_code = col]

Comment: well what is the actual rules.  do you want other_code to over ride terminal_number or do you want to have two columns... it is not clear what exactly you want.

Comment: Well i wasn't aware, How can I have it so that other_code over ride terminal ?

Comment: Post your sample data (covering all possible cases) and the desired output.

Comment: @OVO you have to tell us what you expect it to do.  we can't read your mind, no matter how much we may want (or not want) to do so.

Comment: I would like it to rename all the terminal_numbers from the number values to the names listed; however for driver's who are in terminal lithonia and have other_codes = col i would like the column term to be named col\

Comment: if you want it to be `COL` why does your question say COLUMBUS?

Comment: @ovo - as Hogan mentions in his answer, this sort of mapping _really_ needs to be in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a better way to this kind of translation -- I make a "temporary" table with VALUES statement and then join to that table.  I think this makes it clear how this data could be stored in a table which would be better.

```
SELECT UNIQUE D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME, TERMLIST.NAME AS TERM
FROM DRIVER D
LEFT JOIN (
  VALUES 
     ('0' , 'LITHONIA'  ),
     ('1' , 'MONTGOMERY' ),
     ('2' , 'BOWLING GREEN'),
     ('4' , 'OOLTEWAH'),
     ('40', 'LEXINGTON SOUTH'),
     ('41', 'DURHAM'),
     ('42', 'LEXINGTON'),
     ('43', 'OKC'),
     ('46', 'STEVENSON'),
     ('47', 'TUPELO'),
     ('48', 'HUMBOLDT'),
     ('49', 'MURFREESBORO'),
     ('5' , 'JEFFERSON CTIY'),
     ('50', 'LEWISBURG'),
     ('52', 'SAVANNAH'),
     ('54', 'FRANKLIN'),
     ('6' , 'JACKSONVILLE'),
     ('75', 'VIRGINIA'),
     ('8' , 'ATHENS'),
     ('9' , 'LATTA')
) TERMLIST ON TERMLIST.TN = D.TERMINAL_NUMBER
WHERE D.ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
ORDER BY D.DRIVER_ID, TERMLIST.NAME
```

For your special requirement on two values we do this:

```
SELECT UNIQUE D.DRIVER_ID, D.NAME,
     CASE WHEN D.TERMINAL_NUMBER = '0' AND D.OTHER_CODES = 'COL' THEN 'COL'
          ELSE TERMLIST.NAME END AS TERM 
FROM DRIVER D
LEFT JOIN (
  VALUES 
     ('0' , 'LITHONIA'  ),
     ('1' , 'MONTGOMERY' ),
     ('2' , 'BOWLING GREEN'),
     ('4' , 'OOLTEWAH'),
     ('40', 'LEXINGTON SOUTH'),
     ('41', 'DURHAM'),
     ('42', 'LEXINGTON'),
     ('43', 'OKC'),
     ('46', 'STEVENSON'),
     ('47', 'TUPELO'),
     ('48', 'HUMBOLDT'),
     ('49', 'MURFREESBORO'),
     ('5' , 'JEFFERSON CTIY'),
     ('50', 'LEWISBURG'),
     ('52', 'SAVANNAH'),
     ('54', 'FRANKLIN'),
     ('6' , 'JACKSONVILLE'),
     ('75', 'VIRGINIA'),
     ('8' , 'ATHENS'),
     ('9' , 'LATTA')
) TERMLIST ON TERMLIST.TN = D.TERMINAL_NUMBER
WHERE D.ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'
ORDER BY D.DRIVER_ID, TERMLIST.NAME
```